# Symfony2 API with tables without entities

Tags: api, symfony, doctrine, legacy-code

I have legacy code that has DB connected.I'm trying to add new features for this app with Symfony2. I used Theodo Evolution Bundle to access the legacy session.
First thing that I want to do now, is to build an API that will use data from existing database. This database has tables that are not converted to entities. My question is which is best approach in this case. To use native queries from existing tables in database to build API or to convert tables into entities [I used documentation for this part](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) but I'm not sure will import all relations and everything) and then to build API. Can you please suggest me which is best approach in this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach in my opinion is to work with doctrine entities within the framework and to avoid direct SQL if possible. That is the basic philosophy behind frameworks such as Symfony: the database layer should be abstracted.

The entity-database mapping might be quite more of a hassle at first, because you can't rely on automatic tools to set it up, but once it's done it will be much easier to work out the rest of the application.

Comment: Thank Zephyr for answer. I will implement this approach.